# Partial mocking

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, mocking

I need partial mocking:

```
class Post
  def meth1; meth2; end
  def meth2; nil; end
end

real_model = Post.new
mock_model = SomeMock.new real_model
mock_model.expect :meth1, true
mock_model.validate
mock_model.verify # should return true if #meth2 has worked and false otherwise
```

There is SimpleMock (https://github.com/tatey/simple_mock) but seems it
doesn't accept partial mocking:
https://github.com/tatey/simple_mock/issues/3

Can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typically use [RR](https://github.com/rr/rr), which implements proxies that allow you to create an expectation on a method without overriding the method itself:

The syntax is a bit different. Here is a typical mock:

```
mock(real_model).meth1 { mock_return_value }
```

A proxy mock would handle the problem as you've described it:

```
mock.proxy(real_model).meth1
```

The expectation still must be fulfilled, but your original implementation is executed.

Comment: Thanks very much! Don't you know how is it implemented? I won't use a big package but partial mocking only... I have tried to discover RR's code but... It's complicated? Do you know how is it implemented?